# xbootmgr failing to run a trace, couldn't find a kernel logger

Tags: windows-7, performance, login, logging, diagnostic

I am attempting to run a boot trace on a computer that is slow to log in using xbootmgr.  It is a Windows 7 Professional computer that is on a domain.  Based on the guide on this website: http://www.cluberti.com/blog/2011/07/22/using-xbootmgr-to-trace-boot-shutdown-and-reboot-performance-issues/ I installed the WPT, and ran the following command from the command line as a local admin of the computer:

```
xbootmgr –trace boot -traceFlags BASE+LATENCY+DISK_IO_INIT+DISPATCHER+DRIVERS+FILE_IO+FILE_IO_INIT+NETWORKTRACE+PERF_COUNTER+POWER+PRIORITY+REGISTRY -postBootDelay 300 -resultPath C:\Boot_Trace
```

The issue is strange, it seems that after sitting over night the computer take about 10 minutes to login.  However, I get the following error in the xbootmgr.log file that is created:

```
[2014/04/30-20:07:53.869] Performance Analyzer Power Transition Performance Testing Utility (Microsoft® Windows® Performance Analyzer) Version 6.2.9200 - © 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[2014/04/30-20:07:53.869] Detected Win7RTM physical (ReadyBoot) prefetcher; the SysMain service is auto-started.
[2014/04/30-20:07:53.869] Registering for auto-run with a 300000 msec delay...
[2014/04/30-20:07:53.869] Completed auto-run change.
[2014/04/30-20:07:53.885] Starting trace...
[2014/04/30-20:07:53.947] Enabled boot logging to 'C:\Boot_Trace\boot_BASE+LATENCY+DISK_IO_INIT+DISPATCHER+DRIVERS+FILE_IO+FILE_IO_INIT+NETWORKTRACE+PERF_COUNTER+POWER+PRIORITY+REGISTRY_1_km_premerge.etl'
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.888] Performance Analyzer Power Transition Performance Testing Utility (Microsoft® Windows® Performance Analyzer) Version 6.2.9200 - © 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.888] Detected virtual prefetcher.
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.888] Stopping trace...
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.888] Couldn't find kernel logger in active logger list.
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.888] Couldn't find user-mode logger in active logger list.
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.904] Unable to stop trace.
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.904] Stopping trace...
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.904] Unregistering auto-run...
[2014/05/01-09:39:54.904] Failed to open auto-run reg key with 0x00000005.
```

I'm not sure what it's looking for with regards to the "kernel logger in active logger list" and the subsequent logger error.  How do I fix that and successfully run the trace?

Comment: Does [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/447f8512-9a33-43bd-a1cf-f0ca25b4b33a/unable-to-get-past-second-boot-when-preparing-system-or-otherwise-obtaining-traces-with-xbootmgrexe?forum=wptk_v4) help?

Comment: I don't think so, based on some research, the modification to the registry key they recommend will turn off the Superfetch service, and I can't see how that will solve the problem.  Thank you though.

http://computerstepbystep.com/superfetch_service.html